# Finding checked check boxes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a many-to-many relationship that pretty mush says that **a manager can have many projects and a project can have many managers**. When creating/editing a project I want to present a list of all managers to the user who just check the one they want. This is my projects/_form.html.erb:

```
 <% @allManagers do |m| %>
  <p><%= check_box_tag m.name, m.id, false %> <%= m.name %> </p>
 <% end %>
```

This works nicely, but I don't know how to get the checked ones to the controller. A checked one adds this to the params:

```
"Manager Name" => "2" #name and id
```

How can I check which managers who´s been checked at submit in my controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refactor slightly. I assume that you'll want to end up with a collection of managers (or manager IDs to be precise). Your code should look something like this:

```
<p><%= check_box_tag "manager_ids[]", m.id %> <%= m.name %></p>
```

This should give a collection in the `manager_ids` param. (Notice the square brackets.)

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag